# Vectorizing nested for loops and pointwise multiplication in matlab

Tags: matlab

Long time reader, first time inquisitor.  So I am currently hitting a serious bottleneck from the following code:

```
for kk=1:KT
    parfor jj=1:KT
        umodes(kk,jj,:,:,:) = repmat(squeeze(psi(kk,jj,:,:)), [1,1,no_bands]).*squeeze(umodes(kk,jj,:,:,:));
    end
end
```

In plain language, I need to tile the multi-dimensional array 'psi' across another dimension of length 'no_bands' and then perform pointwise multiplication with the matrix 'umodes'. The issue is that each of the arrays I am working with is large, on the order of 20 GB or more.

What is happening then, I suspect, is that my processors grind to a halt due to cache limits or because data is being paged.  I am reasonably convinced there is no practical way to reduce the size of my arrays, so at this point I am trying to reduce computational overhead to a bare minimum.

If that is not possible, it might be time to think of using a proper programming language where I can enforce pass by reference to avoid unnecessary replication of arrays.

Comment: Are you using local or distributed workers? For local workers, I assume that this code runs faster with a normal `for` because most (maybe all) function you are using are implemented using multiple cores. Vectorizing won't help if you don't have enough memory.

Comment: Hi Daniel, the answer is local.  So, what you are saying is that my attempt at being clever by trying to farm everything out to multiple cores is actually getting in the way of letting matlab do its job?

Comment: Can you make a running sum and only index the components of the matrix being multiplied?  If you don't have unique data in the matrix, why use the memory holding redundant information, right?  This looks like a cousin of a convolution.  Have you considered trying to use fft for part of this?  (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34173/fast-matrix-multiplication)

Answer (score 0):

Often [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) uses less memory than `repmat`. So you can try:

```
for kk=1:KT
    parfor jj=1:KT
        umodes(kk,jj,:,:,:) = bsxfun(@times, squeeze(psi(kk,jj,:,:)), squeeze(umodes(kk,jj,:,:,:)));
    end
end
```

Or you can vectorize the two loops. Vectorizing is usually faster, although not necessarily more memory-efficient, so I'm not sure it helps in your case. In any case, `bsxfun` [benefits from multihreading](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95958):

```
umodes = bsxfun(@times, psi, umodes);
```

Comment: Thanks Luis.  It is spooky that there is a function that works that way, but oh well, such is Matlab.

Comment: Do you mean `bsxfun`? Yes, it caused a great impression on me when I discovered it some months ago